# view in base.html django

Tags: python, django, view

I have notification scrollbar like on fb or twitter. Top menu.html is directly included by base.html Unfortunatelly, I can use only User method there. Is it possible to not write in every view that I need notifications? I want to once paste in one view and have it always in top menu.html which is in base!

`from intarface import 
menu_nots`

`nots = menu_nots(request)`

Answer (score 2):

It is possible. Try [writing your own context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors).

```
def add_notifications(request):
    """ Adds Facebook notifications to the view context. """
    return {'notifications': menu_nots(request)}
```

Next, add it to your TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS in settings.py.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best way to solve your problem by using a inclusion tags:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags

```
@register.inclusion_tag('menu.html')
def show_menu():
    #menu logic2
```

in base.html:

```
<html>
    ...
    {% show_menu %}
    ...
</html>
```

function of inclusion tag will run on every request on every pages

Answer (score 0):

Use [messages](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/) %username% !

view

```
from django.contrib import messages

messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Hello world.')
messages.debug(request, '%s SQL statements were executed.' % count)
messages.info(request, 'Three credits remain in your account.')
messages.success(request, 'Profile details updated.')
messages.warning(request, 'Your account expires in three days.')
messages.error(request, 'Document deleted.')
```

template

```
{% if messages %}
    <ul class="messages">
    {% for message in messages %}
        <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

add to setting.py part of TEMPLATE append to `context_processors` list -> `app_name.view.base,`